# bibtex don't work

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Can someone help me please!

I run my bibtex file but I received the following error message:

```
line 61 of file EH.aux
 : \bibstyle{IEEEtran
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open database file RefEH.bib
---line 62 of file EH.aux
 : \bibdata{RefEH
 :               }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file EH.aux
I found no style file---while reading file EH.aux
```

Comment: please show us a sample of your code. What exactly is the bane of your `/bib` file. How do you specify its name in the document?

Comment: \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}%IEEEtran  %plain %ieeetr
 \bibliography{RefEH}

Comment: it is saying it can't find `RefEH.bib` do you have that file in the same folder as your document?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: You say "of course" but if it was there and readable bibtex should find it, so there is something you are not telling us. Make a small complete test file that shows the problem so people can reproduce the error and debug, and show the log you get with the test file. Currently you are just asking "why does bibtex give a file not found error" ? and with no other information hard to suggest any answer other than the file is not readable, or bibtex is being run in the wrong place.

Comment: Is it possible, that you have `RefEH.bib.bib` in your folder?

Comment: my problem is that bst file couldn't be opened. someone have the solution for this ??